# woocommerce order to mark as completed upon visiting a specific page

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I want a woocommerce order to be automatically marked as completed upon visiting a specific page in WordPress

This specific page will have the `order_id` in GET variable. Now what i need to know is how to find an order by `order_id` and mark the status as completed on a specific WordPress page.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with following piece of code:

```
if(is_page('page_title')){
    $order = new WC_Order($_GET['your_order_id']);
    //wc-completed, wc-processing
    $update_status = array('ID'=>$_GET['your_order_id'],'post_status'=>'wc-completed');
    wp_update_post( $update_status );
}
```

**First** check whether It is on your specific page or not.

**Second** thing is to get your order

**Third** step is to update **status** of order.

Let me know if you have any doubt.

**EDITED**

You can refer [codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_page#Examples) for more details on `is_page`.

If you have **page_id** then you need to put condition like `if(is_page(42))` where **42** is ID of your page.

Comment: Hey, I have the page by ID, so what should be in is_page also can I just simply do $order = new WC_Order($_GET['your_order_id']);
    //wc-completed, wc-processing
    $update_status = array('ID'=>$_GET['your_order_id'],'post_status'=>'wc-completed');
    wp_update_post( $update_status ); because the specific url is not changed.

Comment: still couldt get the order status to get updated. I am using insert php plugin  as well. So with insert php plugin I am embedding php on a specified wordpress page. I embedded the above php snippet but my order status does not change to complete

Comment: I have not used that plugin but it seems that you are putting that in WordPress Editor. If so How will you get order_id in GET parameter ?
__NOTE:__ `Insert PHP` is not compatible up to Latest Version.

Comment: I don't know the exact use and exact pages. So I would say put it in the end of  your `header.php` . As it is just updating, it won't make any difference. 


Also Make sure that you put correct page_id in `if(is_page())` condition and you are also getting __order ID__ in `$_GET` parameters.

Comment: Its working in the header.php but I will try with a new page template now

Comment: If its working, then you can accept it as answer :)

You can make [custom template](http://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/creating-custom-page-templates-in-wordpress/?utm_expid=3606929-40.lszTaIEzTbifDhvhVdd39A.0&utm_referrer=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.co.in%2Furl%3Fsa%3Dt%26rct%3Dj%26q%3D%26esrc%3Ds%26source%3Dweb%26cd%3D4%26ved%3D0CDMQFjAD%26url%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Fpremium.wpmudev.org%252Fblog%252Fcreating-custom-page-templates-in-wordpress%252F%26ei%3DOTaVVZDLINCLuwS78Bw%26usg%3DAFQjCNHJXCo7ootGeHNyAGBJKCDMAPo62A%26sig2%3D2bPFVvJJVc_1_oYzzqC6rQ%26bvm%3Dbv.96952980%2Cd.c2E) to achieve it.

Answer (score 0):

So, Rohil_PHPBeginner's answer works like a charme. If you urgently search for a "just copy and paste" solution and have no time to figure things out, go ahead and use this ready to use snippet for your functions.php:

**Don't forget to replace the number 42 with the page id of your desired page that will handle as an order-completion-url. Afterwards you can call the order completion by url by: http://your-url.com/yourdeletionpage/?your_order_id=ORDER_ID_TO_BE_COMPLETED**

```
function my_abhaken() {
if(is_page(42)){
$order = new WC_Order($_GET['your_order_id']);
//wc-completed, wc-processing
$update_status = array('ID'=>$_GET['your_order_id'],'post_status'=>'wc-completed');
wp_update_post( $update_status );
}
}
add_action('wp_head', 'my_abhaken');
```